# How to make dual boot by getting free space from Windows XP Primary Drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot, disk-space

I want to go for `Dual boot` with `Windows XP` and `Ubuntu` currently, `Windows` already installed in system with partitions as

`C: 270GB (Primary Drive);D:10 GB and E:92 GB`

I want to get `100 GB` from `C:` drive and want add it to `D:` So, that I can install `Ubuntu` in `D:`, how can I do this without installing `windows` again.

Comment: I would just use gparted that is on the ubuntu live cd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Download [miniTool Partition Wizard](http://partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)
2: Defrag C:\ and D:\ drives 
3: Run miniTool wizard
4: Shrink C:\ by 100GB
5: Extend D:\ by adding the new 100gb partition to it
6: Perform quick format for good measure
7: Install Ubuntu

Also, if you just want to explore Ubuntu without messing around with partitions and installs you can simply download [Ubuntu live](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) and run it directly off a USB drive.

Comment: Thanks Campbell,I'll try it before that I've not get your last two lines in answer

Comment: If you want to run Ubuntu without installing it on the computer, then download Ubuntu live and put it on a USB drive. Go into BIOS and set your USB drive as primary boot device and restart computer. Ubuntu will load up without installing and allow you to mess around with it.

Comment: means without installing manually I can use Ubuntu still ?

Comment: Yes. run it without installing it.

Comment: No, I want to install it,can I install in D-drive without any issues na ?

Comment: @Mahesh.D yes you can. In fact, you can resize the partition during the Ubuntu install, you don't need to do it beforehand.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu in D-drive but boot menu is not showing, windows is getting loaded automatically.

Comment: @Mahesh.D: Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a LiveCD.

Comment: @Karan: I've found similar answer in `askubuntu` but it was not worked for me, is there any other solution.Thanks

Comment: @Mahesh.D: I see your other question now. The Ubuntu experts there should be able to sort this out for you easily.